# Django celery and celery-beat daemonizing script error

Tags: django, celery, celery-task, celerybeat, celeryd

Im going to  set periodic tasks with celery for what im trying to daemonize a django celery process in a test server using a script (referenced on the official website):

[Init-script: celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#daemonizing)

So, this is my **celeryd** file:

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most people will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="indicators"
#   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
#   for each in CELERYD_OPTS (see `celery multi --help` for examples):
#CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
#   alternatively, you can specify the number of nodes to start:
#CELERYD_NODES=10

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
#CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
CELERY_BIN="/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
#CELERY_APP="sgiprocess"
# or fully qualified:
CELERY_APP="indicator.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/opt/pymis/reps/indicator_repository/indicator_ms/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/worker1.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/worker1.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists, e.g. nobody).
CELERYD_USER="celeryuser"
CELERYD_GROUP="mygroup"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

This is my **celerybeat** file:

```
# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
#CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
CELERY_BIN="/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
#CELERY_APP="sgiprocess"
# or fully qualified:
CELERY_APP="indicator.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/opt/pymis/reps/indicators_repository/indicator_ms/"

# Extra arguments to celerybeat
CELERYBEAT_OPTS="--schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule"
```

This is my error trace:

```
(indicators_test) user@server:/opt/pymis/reps/indicator_repository/indicator_ms$ sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd restart
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd

celery multi v4.0.2 (latentcall)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    _main()
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 481, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 503, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 355, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 506, in symbol_by_name
    return imports.symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/pymis/reps/indicator_repository/indicator_ms/indicator/tasks.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .models import Value
  File "/opt/pymis/reps/indicator_repository/indicator_ms/indicator/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/opt/pymis/envs/indicators/indicators_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
> Restarting node indicators@EMT-LIBREAPP: * Child terminated with exit code 1
FAILED
```

Thing is, when i manually initiate celery and celerybeat with:

```
celery -A config worker -l info
celery -A config beat
```

I don't get any error and everything loads well.

Update: This is my celery.py file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
import os


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.test')
app = Celery('indicators')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Update 2: This is my directory tree

```
indicator_ms (project root)
├── config
│   ├── settings
│   │    ├── __init__.py
│   │    ├── local.py
│   │    ├── test.py
│   │    └── production.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py    
│ 
└── indicators (app)
    ├── __init__.py
    └── tasks.py
```

and this is the **init**.py file inside config folder (not settings folder)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As django celery tasks aren't properly a proyect module,we need to call the  [django.setup()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) method in our respective tasks modules.

In my case the solution was to set this lines inside task.py file before any other project related import:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing... Are you married to this project structure? :D

Because you are just starting with celery, I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that you can move `celery.py`.

---

You could try exporting your settings module in your `celeryd` file if it's in a custom path.

```
# regular celeryd config stuff...

# projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.production
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/my_project/
```

And use exactly `'indicator_celery.settings'` in your `celery.py` file, not `config.settings.local`

```
# celery.py file

from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'indicator_celery.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('indicator_celery')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

also `indicator_celery.__init__` file shoudl be like this:

```
# celery app init file
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app  # noqa
```

---

final directory tree:

```
indicator_ms (project root)
├── config
│   ├── settings
│   │    ├── __init__.py
│   │    ├── local.py
│   │    ├── test.py
│   │    └── production.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py    
├── indicator_celery
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── celery.py
└── indicators (app)
    ├── __init__.py
    └── tasks.py
```

Comment: When you say 'myapp.settings' you mean the settings.py ?...its because my settings are divided by environments (one for local, one for test...beign local my current development environment)

Comment: please try with newly provided celery.py file.

Comment: You are missing the point. Your `celery.py` is in `indicators` dir, right? Please set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ` to `indicators.settings`.

Comment: Also, the order of stuff matters ;)

Comment: I tried the celery.py you post me and change the imports order but i get the same error...what i don't get it's why you want me to add the indicators.settings to the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ( in my project, settings it's just a dir with different config files established by environments ( local, test, production...)). Also when i run celery manually with the lines i posted above it all works fine.

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional info regarding celery app `__init__.py` file and what I'm guessing is your project directory tree.

Comment: I've updated the question with more info about my project directory, so you can tell me how to do it with that structure

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer with proposed dir structure change for you.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand, you're setting indicator_celery.settings but there's no setting file inside that dir, so how it will recognize it ?...also, why celery configuration needs modification because when i run the celery manually it works well. How is that related to the init script ?

Comment: The part of recognising settings works thanks to the code in __init__.py. It actually isn't the same to run celery just like a command locally and through a celeryd init script. Further on, this way Celery isn't importing your settings file by python path, but is using the one that was imported using line `from django.conf import settings`. It's a bit convoluted I guess. I have the same exact project structure that I have described in my answer on several separate projects, so I'm basing my answer on that.

Comment: I see...could you please explain why i have to change my celery configuration if im going to run my init script or manually ?

Answer (score 1):

To further @mislav's point, there is an important caveat in the celery docs about [configuration of your celery app instance](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#example-django-configuration):

> Django users now uses the exact same template as above, **but make sure that the module that defines your Celery app instance also sets a default value for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`** as shown in the example Django project in First steps with Django.

(emphasis added)

So make sure something similar to the following line(s) appear in your celery.py

```
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('my_project_name')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

If all else fails, update the initd script to source your virtual environment before you invoke celery.

Comment: I already did that and still doesn't work, please check my question update